# How to debug Google App Engine API on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, google-app-engine, debugging

I started developing Android apps using Google App Engine, and I was wondering, is there a way to debug the API code as I send requests from the client code? And if not, what is the most efficient way of debugging the API code?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging?hl=nl

Comment: Are you talking about remote debug (on production server) or local debug (on development server) ?

Comment: No, I need to debug an API that I wrote using GAE without any web interface. The requests come only from the Android app and I want to follow this request to the ApiMethod and debug it the way Eclipse debug regular code.

Comment: I deployed my app to the GAE so either way will be OK, but I think the local debug would be more comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

You just launch the AppEngine app in debug mode locally, and then launch the Android App (phone or emulator, both will work) pointing to localhost instead of the deployed version like this:

```
String serviceUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8888/yourAppName";
```

You can't just say `localhost` because that's the device itself. After you do this you can debug normally with break-points on your code etc.

I am unaware of the existence of remote debugging tools for appengine, but unless you are trying to troubleshoot problems that appear only once you deploy there's no reason to do that.

Comment: And then I can put breakpoints in the API code and have a line-by-line debugging?

Comment: @oriwass exactly, yes - standard Java debugging

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me, are you sure this is all I'm supposed to do to make it work?

Comment: @oriwass yes - I am doing it myself, it would help if you can update your post with more details. Are you running the AppEngine app as debug (not just run) and is it just that it doesn't hit the break-points?

Comment: I'm running both the AppEngine app and the Android app as debug, the first one as "web application", and yes - it just doesn't hit break-points. Maybe it's still accessing the deployed AppEngine app? Where do I need to change in the code so it will access the local code and not the remote one?

Comment: "Where do I need to change in the code so it will access the local code and not the remote one?": only you can access that question I am afraid. To avoid confusion, I would suggest you to run only the AppEngine app, create a test servlet (you should have a default one if you didn't delete it) put a breakpoint in there and access the url on the browser (http://localhost:8888/AppName) and make sure you can debug it like that, if you can't well... you're doing something wrong, but I really don't have enough information to tell you what :)